# Count in output vars with terraform 0.12+

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I conditionally create a resource with count:

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "this" {
  count       = var.create_kms_key == true ? 1 : 0
  ...
}
```

How do I then conditionally output the value of this resource?  I tried playing around and Terraform seems to contradict itself

First it tells me to use count in output.

```
For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
    aws_kms_key.this[count.index]
```

Then when I try that it says I can't use count.

```
The "count" object can be used only in "resource" and "data" blocks, and only
when the "count" argument is set.
```

Previously we were able to do something like below but this now triggers the count error I posted previously.

```
output "kms_key_arn" {
    value = aws_kms_key.this.*.arn
}
```

Any idea how this works now?

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When `count` is set for a resource, references to that resource then return a list of objects rather than a single object, and so we need to write our other expressions with that in mind.

In your case, that list can either have zero or one elements, and so we must handle both of those cases in any expression that refers to it.

To write an output that propagates an attribute from that resource, we need to decide what we'll return in the situation where the list is empty. For example, we could choose to set the output to `null` in that case:

```
output "kms_key_arn" {
    value = concat(aws_kms_key.this.*.arn, [null])[0]
}
```

The technique here is to change from having a list with zero or one elements into a list with one or two elements, and then take the first element. There are two possibilities for what that `concat` function might return:

```
["arn:aws:....", null]
[null]
```

In both cases, it is valid to take the zeroth element using `[0]`. In the second case, it will select `null` as the result.

---

If you have other resources that are also conditional on `var.create_kms_key`, there is a variant on this approach:

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "example" {
  count = var.create_kms_key ? 1 : 0

  # ...
}

resource "anything_else" "example" {
  count = length(aws_kms_key.example) # only if KMS key is created

  any_argument = aws_kms_key.example[count.index].arn
}
```

This variant relies on the fact that both of these resources have the same value for `count` and thus we can use `count.index` in the second resource in order to correlate with instances of the first. `count.index` can only be used inside a resource where `count` is set, but in this particular situation it *is* set, and because we set `count` to the length of the other resource we know that all `count.index` values will be in range for that resource's object list.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this and thanks for all your work on TF.  In the end my issue here was that in another piece of code i wasn't using count hence why the TF errors seemed contradictory.  Everything was actually working as intended.